# How can we find all the arrangements of a string 5 characters long?

Tags: cobol

Using java, finding the arrangements is pretty easy and computable.

Using COBOL as the programming language, I am finding it difficult to code it off.

```
PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I=5
 COMPUTE X = 5-I                        
 PERFORM VARYING J FROM I BY 1 UNTIL J=X
    MOVE WORD(I,1) TO TEMP1.            
    MOVE WORD(J,1) TO TEMP2.
```

I have a code sample, I am not sure as it is incomplete and I wonder if I am on the right way of doing it.

Comment: +1 for asking a COBOL question. Can you write recursive function in COBOL?

Comment: You can write a recursive program in COBOL....same thing.  This is the sort of thing that a Bose-Nelson generator would spit out easily.

Comment: Why did you assign the DB2 tag to a COBOL programming question?

Comment: In any case if I want to use a database, it would be DB2. The reason why I tagged DB2.

Comment: It would be less confusing to tag the question for what it actually involves, not what it could involve later. Should you decide to pursue a DB2 solution to this problem, just open a new question and tag it as DB2 (and probably SQL, too).

Comment: @Ingo, you can't write functions in COBOL. Why'd you need recursion?

Comment: @BillWoodger because "permutations" is a one liner with recursion. Well, in Haskell at least.

Comment: @JoeZitzelberger Thanks for introducing me to Bose-Nelson sorting networks, but I fail to see how they might relate to this question.

Comment: The purpose is to take all permutations of a given small set of characters and generate source code to order them with the swap() function.  But the first half of that is that for a given length, and a given range of values in each character, it will generate that pattern, so you can use the same algorithm to, for example, generate source text to populate a table with all possible values for a given range of inputs.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved using just about any programming language (including COBOL), with or without recursion. A recursive
solution is trivial, the non-recursive solution is a bit more interesting. Here is a COBOL, non-recursive implementation.

**A few observations:**

Arrangements may be built iteratively from an empty base case and a list of characters to build the arrangements from.
On each iteration the next character
is taken from the input list and inserted at all possible positions of base cases from the prior iteration. These new strings become the base case for
the next iteration. When the input list becomes empty the base case contains all possible arrangements.

Consider building arrangements of 3 characters this way:

```
Iteration 0 => Input[a, b, c] introduce []: BaseCases[[]]
Iteration 1 => Input[b, c] introduce [a]: BaseCases[[a]]
Iteration 2 => Input[c] introduce [b]: BaseCases[[b a], [a b]]
Iteration 3 => Input [] introduce [c]: BaseCases[[c b a], [b c a], [b a c], [c b a], [b c a], [a b c]]
```

Note that the number of strings in the final base case is equal to factorial(length(input)). In the above example three characters
were introduced giving 3! = 6 strings in the final base case.

Since the number of strings to be generated in any given iteration is known at the time of the iteration and that number is
larger than the previous iteration we can use the same array structure to hold the base cases for both iterations at the same time.
This is done by building the new base case starting at the highest subscript and working backwards. The same is done when extracting
base patterns generated on the prior iteration. This explains why subscripting in the following program is done
in reverse order (counting down instead of up).

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID ARRANGE.

   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01.
       02 ARRANGEMENT-TABLE.
          03 ARRANGEMENT PIC X(5) OCCURS 120 TIMES.
   01  INPUT-CHARS       PIC X(5) VALUE 'abcde'.
   01  BASE-ARRANGEMENT  PIC X(5).
   01  CURR-CHAR         PIC X.
   01  I                 PIC S9(4) BINARY.
   01  J                 PIC S9(4) BINARY.
   01  K                 PIC S9(4) BINARY.
   01  L                 PIC S9(4) BINARY.
   01  CURR-FACT         PIC S9(9) BINARY.
   01  PREV-FACT         PIC S9(9) BINARY.
   01  COMP-FACT         PIC S9(9) BINARY.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
  *
  *    Verify that the Arrangement table is large enough to hold
  *    all possible arrangements of the letters in INPUT-CHARS.
  *
       COMPUTE COMP-FACT =
               FUNCTION FACTORIAL (LENGTH OF INPUT-CHARS)
       IF COMP-FACT > LENGTH OF ARRANGEMENT-TABLE /
                      LENGTH OF ARRANGEMENT(1)
          DISPLAY 'ARRANGEMENT-TABLE is too small.'
          GOBACK
       END-IF
       IF LENGTH OF ARRANGEMENT(1) < LENGTH OF INPUT-CHARS
          DISPLAY 'INPUT-CHARS too long for ARRANGEMENT.'
          GOBACK
       END-IF
       IF LENGTH OF BASE-ARRANGEMENT < LENGTH OF ARRANGEMENT(1)
          DISPLAY 'BASE-ARRANGEMENT is too small for ARRANGEMENT.'
          GOBACK
       END-IF

       MOVE SPACES TO ARRANGEMENT(1)

       DISPLAY 'Starting sequence: ' INPUT-CHARS
  *
  *    Generate all possible arrangements of INPUT-CHARS...
  *
  *       I counts through the set of INPUT-CHARS used in string geneation
  *       J counts down from arrangements built on previous iteration
  *       K counts to number of characters in new expanded base case
  *       L counts down from arrangements to be build in current iteration
  *
  *       CURR-FACT is the factorial of the current iteration number
  *       PREV-FACT is the factorial of the previous iteration
  *       CURR-CHAR is the character to add into existing base cases

       MOVE 1 TO CURR-FACT
       PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1
                 UNTIL I > LENGTH OF INPUT-CHARS
          MOVE CURR-FACT TO PREV-FACT
          COMPUTE CURR-FACT = PREV-FACT * I
          MOVE INPUT-CHARS(I:1) TO CURR-CHAR
          MOVE CURR-FACT TO L
          PERFORM VARYING J FROM PREV-FACT BY -1
                    UNTIL J = ZERO
             PERFORM VARYING K FROM 1 BY 1
               UNTIL K > I
               MOVE ARRANGEMENT(J) TO BASE-ARRANGEMENT
               PERFORM NEW-ARRANGEMENT
               COMPUTE L = L - 1
             END-PERFORM
          END-PERFORM
       END-PERFORM
  *
  *    List generated patters...
  *
       COMPUTE COMP-FACT =
               FUNCTION FACTORIAL(LENGTH OF INPUT-CHARS)
       PERFORM VARYING I FROM COMP-FACT BY -1
                 UNTIL I < 1
          DISPLAY ARRANGEMENT(I)
       END-PERFORM
       GOBACK
       .
   NEW-ARRANGEMENT.
  *
  *    Build a new character arrangement by placing
  *    CURR-CHAR into position K of a given
  *    BASE-ARRANGEMENT
  *
       MOVE SPACES    TO ARRANGEMENT(L)
       MOVE CURR-CHAR TO ARRANGEMENT(L)(K:1)
       IF K > 1
          MOVE BASE-ARRANGEMENT(1:K - 1)
            TO ARRANGEMENT(L)(1:K - 1)
       END-IF
       IF K <= PREV-FACT
          MOVE BASE-ARRANGEMENT(K:)
            TO ARRANGEMENT(L)(K + 1:)
       END-IF
       .
```

**Final Note:**
If the input string contains repeated characters then some of the patters will be repeated. This solution does not take this "complication" into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation of Ingo's blueprint (see above) in COBOL.  I offer it because it is a different algorithm than the ones that NealB and Bill Woodger provided.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. PERMUTATION.
  * GENERATE PERMUTATIONS FROM A SET OF FIVE ELEMENTS
  * WITHOUT USING RECURSION

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  CHAR-SET                    PIC X(5) VALUE 'ABCDE'.
   01  SOLUTION                    PIC X(5).
   01  SOLUTION-COUNT              PIC 999 VALUE ZERO.
   01  INDEXES.
       02  I                       PIC 9.
       02  J                       PIC 9.
       02  K                       PIC 9.
       02  L                       PIC 9.
       02  M                       PIC 9.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN.
  * IGNORED REGULAR INDENTING TO SIMPLIFY CODE
       PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I > 5
       PERFORM VARYING J FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL J > 5
       IF J NOT = I
       PERFORM VARYING K FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL K > 5
       IF K NOT = J AND K NOT = I
       PERFORM VARYING L FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL L > 5
       IF L NOT = K AND L NOT = J AND L NOT = I
       PERFORM VARYING M FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL M > 5
       IF M NOT = L AND M NOT = K AND M NOT = J AND M NOT = I
            ADD 1 TO SOLUTION-COUNT END-ADD
            DISPLAY SOLUTION-COUNT ' ' WITH NO ADVANCING
            END-DISPLAY
            MOVE CHAR-SET(I:1) TO SOLUTION (1:1)
            MOVE CHAR-SET(J:1) TO SOLUTION (2:1)
            MOVE CHAR-SET(K:1) TO SOLUTION (3:1)
            MOVE CHAR-SET(L:1) TO SOLUTION (4:1)
            MOVE CHAR-SET(M:1) TO SOLUTION (5:1)
            DISPLAY SOLUTION END-DISPLAY
       END-IF
       END-PERFORM
       END-IF
       END-PERFORM
       END-IF
       END-PERFORM
       END-IF
       END-PERFORM
       END-PERFORM
       STOP RUN
       .
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you'd need a n-fold nested loop to make the permutations of n elements. The following provides a blueprint:

```
for i = 1 to 5
  for j = 1 to 5 if j != i
    for k = 1 to 5 if k != j && k != i
      for m = 1 to 5 if m != k && m != j && m != i
        for n = 1 to 5 if n != m && n != k && n != j && n != i
          solution = (i,j,k,m,n)
```

This way, you get 120 solutions.
If it is needed, you can then replace the indexes by the actual characters at the respective positions.

To solve it with SQL assumes we have a table with 5 distinct rows:

```
CREATE NUMBERS (VAL INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO NUMBERS VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO NUMBERS VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO NUMBERS VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO NUMBERS VALUES(4);
INSERT INTO NUMBERS VALUES(5);
SELECT VAL I, VAL J, VAL K, VAL M, VAL N FROM NUMBERS WHERE
    I <> J 
    AND K <> I AND K <> J
    AND M <> I AND M <> J AND M <> K
    AND N <> I AND N <> J AND N <> K AND N <> M;
```

Not sure if the SQL syntax is right, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

With "value 1" fixed in position one, go through the loop once generating the 24 cobminations.

Then, "making space for it first", place Value 1 in column 2. Then Value 1 in Column 3. Column 4. Column 5.

Or

Take the initial results, that's one set, then "revolve" all the values in the results (1 = 2, 2 = 3, 3 = 4, 4 = 5, 5 = 1). Thats second result set. Do that three more times.

With either, you can include the "full results" from the one iteration to get the "pattern" of 24 results.

As an example, the following can be added to Valdis Grinbergs's code:

In the WORKING-STORAGE SECTION:

```
01  SAVE-SOLUTION.
    02  SAVE-IT                 PIC X.
    02  FILLER                  PIC X(4).
```

In the PROCEDURE DIVISION:

Change the first PERFORM to

```
MOVE 1 TO I
```

After each SOLUTION is displayed:

```
PERFORM SOLUTIONS-FOR-REMAINING-VALUES
```

Which is, for the "column insertion" version:

```
   SOLUTIONS-FOR-REMAINING-VALUES.
       MOVE SOLUTION                TO SAVE-SOLUTION
       MOVE SOLUTION (2:1)          TO SOLUTION (1:1)
       MOVE SAVE-IT                 TO SOLUTION (2:1) 
       ADD 1                        TO SOLUTION-COUNT 
       DISPLAY SOLUTION 
       MOVE SAVE-SOLUTION           TO SOLUTION
       MOVE SOLUTION (3:1)          TO SOLUTION (1:1)
       MOVE SAVE-IT                 TO SOLUTION (3:1) 
       ADD 1                        TO SOLUTION-COUNT 
       DISPLAY SOLUTION 
       MOVE SAVE-SOLUTION           TO SOLUTION
       MOVE SOLUTION (4:1)          TO SOLUTION (1:1)
       MOVE SAVE-IT                 TO SOLUTION (4:1) 
       ADD 1                        TO SOLUTION-COUNT 
       DISPLAY SOLUTION 
       MOVE SAVE-SOLUTION           TO SOLUTION
       MOVE SOLUTION (5:1)          TO SOLUTION (1:1)
       MOVE SAVE-IT                 TO SOLUTION (5:1) 
       ADD 1                        TO SOLUTION-COUNT 
       DISPLAY SOLUTION 
       .
```

And for the "repeating transposition" version:

```
   SOLUTIONS-FOR-REMAINING-VALUES.
       PERFORM 4 TIMES
           MOVE SOLUTION (1:1) TO SAVE-IT
           MOVE SOLUTION (2:1) TO SOLUTION (1:1)
           MOVE SOLUTION (3:1) TO SOLUTION (2:1)
           MOVE SOLUTION (4:1) TO SOLUTION (3:1)
           MOVE SOLUTION (5:1) TO SOLUTION (4:1)
           MOVE SAVE-IT TO SOLUTION (5:1)
           ADD 1 TO SOLUTION-COUNT 
           DISPLAY SOLUTION 
       END-PERFORM
       .
```

Of course, the paragraph I've added could be done as a loop, but I want to concentrate on showing what is happening, not on how to write a loop in COBOL.

The two different "solutions" are actually two implementations of the same thing. Once the "pattern" has been established, the other 4/5 of the output can be generated by simply varying the content within the fixed pattern.

The loops in the original code can be worked on.

If, for an actual application, performance is a main requirement, then just realise that the "pattern" is known before a line of code is written. The code just saves you writing 24 results by hand. For performance, and with a small-enough "pattern", just code it out, forget the loops.

And I wouldn't use all the "reference modification" myself, I've just left it there from the original.

Now, two versions without loops.Based on the fact that the "pattern" for the first 24 solutions is known beforehand, and that the remaining solutions (already known, but not needed to be coded in the same way) can easily be derived from that.

Rotating values.

```
ID DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. PROTATE.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  CHAR-SET                    PIC X(5) VALUE 'ABCDE'.
01  SOLUTION                    PIC X(5).
01  SOLUTION-COUNT     binary   PIC 9(4) VALUE ZERO.
01  INDEXES.
    02  COLUMN-1              binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  COLUMN-2              binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  COLUMN-3              binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  COLUMN-4              binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  COLUMN-5              binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  ICOL-3                binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  ICOL-4                binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  ICOL-5                binary         PIC 9(4).
01  SAVE-SOLUTION.
    02  SAVE-IT                 PIC X.
    02  FILLER                  PIC X(4).

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MAIN-para.
    MOVE 1 TO COLUMN-1 
    MOVE 2 TO COLUMN-2
    MOVE 3 TO ICOL-3
    MOVE 4 TO ICOL-4
    MOVE 5 TO ICOL-5
    PERFORM SIX-SOLUTIONS
    MOVE 3 TO COLUMN-2
    MOVE 2 TO ICOL-3
    MOVE 4 TO ICOL-4
    MOVE 5 TO ICOL-5
    PERFORM SIX-SOLUTIONS
    MOVE 4 TO COLUMN-2
    MOVE 2 TO ICOL-3
    MOVE 3 TO ICOL-4
    MOVE 5 TO ICOL-5
    PERFORM SIX-SOLUTIONS
    MOVE 5 TO COLUMN-2
    MOVE 2 TO ICOL-3
    MOVE 3 TO ICOL-4
    MOVE 4 TO ICOL-5
    PERFORM SIX-SOLUTIONS
    DISPLAY SOLUTION-COUNT
    STOP RUN
    .
SIX-SOLUTIONS.
    MOVE ICOL-3 TO COLUMN-3
    MOVE ICOL-4 TO COLUMN-4
    MOVE ICOL-5 TO COLUMN-5
    PERFORM A-SOLUTION
    MOVE ICOL-5 TO COLUMN-4
    MOVE ICOL-4 TO COLUMN-5
    PERFORM A-SOLUTION
    MOVE ICOL-4 TO COLUMN-3
    MOVE ICOL-3 TO COLUMN-4
    MOVE ICOL-5 TO COLUMN-5
    PERFORM A-SOLUTION
    MOVE ICOL-5 TO COLUMN-4
    MOVE ICOL-3 TO COLUMN-5
    PERFORM A-SOLUTION
    MOVE ICOL-5 TO COLUMN-3
    MOVE ICOL-3 TO COLUMN-4
    MOVE ICOL-4 TO COLUMN-5
    PERFORM A-SOLUTION
    MOVE ICOL-4 TO COLUMN-4
    MOVE ICOL-3 TO COLUMN-5
    PERFORM A-SOLUTION
    .
A-SOLUTION.
    MOVE CHAR-SET ( 1 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 1 : 1 )
    MOVE CHAR-SET ( COLUMN-2 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 2 : 1 )
    MOVE CHAR-SET ( COLUMN-3 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 3 : 1 )
    MOVE CHAR-SET ( COLUMN-4 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 4 : 1 )
    MOVE CHAR-SET ( COLUMN-5 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 5 : 1 )
    PERFORM SOLUTION-READY
    PERFORM SOLUTIONS-FOR-REMAINING-VALUES
    .
SOLUTIONS-FOR-REMAINING-VALUES.
    MOVE SOLUTION TO SAVE-SOLUTION
    MOVE SOLUTION ( 2 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 1 : 1 )
    MOVE SAVE-IT TO SOLUTION ( 2 : 1 ) 
    PERFORM SOLUTION-READY
    MOVE SAVE-SOLUTION TO SOLUTION
    MOVE SOLUTION ( 3 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 1 : 1 )
    MOVE SAVE-IT TO SOLUTION ( 3 : 1 ) 
    PERFORM SOLUTION-READY
    MOVE SAVE-SOLUTION TO SOLUTION
    MOVE SOLUTION ( 4 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 1 : 1 )
    MOVE SAVE-IT TO SOLUTION ( 4 : 1 ) 
    PERFORM SOLUTION-READY
    MOVE SAVE-SOLUTION TO SOLUTION
    MOVE SOLUTION ( 5 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 1 : 1 )
    MOVE SAVE-IT TO SOLUTION ( 5 : 1 ) 
    PERFORM SOLUTION-READY
    .
SOLUTION-READY.
    ADD 1 TO SOLUTION-COUNT 
    DISPLAY SOLUTION 
    .
```

Column Inserting:

```
ID DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. PCOLINS.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  CHAR-SET                    PIC X(5) VALUE 'ABCDE'.
01  SOLUTION                    PIC X(5).
01  SOLUTION-COUNT     binary   PIC 9(4) VALUE ZERO.
01  INDEXES.
    02  COLUMN-1              binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  COLUMN-2              binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  COLUMN-3              binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  COLUMN-4              binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  COLUMN-5              binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  ICOL-3                binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  ICOL-4                binary         PIC 9(4).
    02  ICOL-5                binary         PIC 9(4).
01  SAVE-SOLUTION.
    02  SAVE-IT                 PIC X.
    02  FILLER                  PIC X(4).     

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MAIN-para.
    MOVE 1 TO COLUMN-1 
    MOVE 2 TO COLUMN-2
    MOVE 3 TO ICOL-3
    MOVE 4 TO ICOL-4
    MOVE 5 TO ICOL-5
    PERFORM SIX-SOLUTIONS
    MOVE 3 TO COLUMN-2
    MOVE 2 TO ICOL-3
    MOVE 4 TO ICOL-4
    MOVE 5 TO ICOL-5
    PERFORM SIX-SOLUTIONS
    MOVE 4 TO COLUMN-2
    MOVE 2 TO ICOL-3
    MOVE 3 TO ICOL-4
    MOVE 5 TO ICOL-5
    PERFORM SIX-SOLUTIONS
    MOVE 5 TO COLUMN-2
    MOVE 2 TO ICOL-3
    MOVE 3 TO ICOL-4
    MOVE 4 TO ICOL-5
    PERFORM SIX-SOLUTIONS
    DISPLAY SOLUTION-COUNT
    STOP RUN
    .
SIX-SOLUTIONS.
    MOVE ICOL-3 TO COLUMN-3
    MOVE ICOL-4 TO COLUMN-4
    MOVE ICOL-5 TO COLUMN-5
    PERFORM A-SOLUTION
    MOVE ICOL-5 TO COLUMN-4
    MOVE ICOL-4 TO COLUMN-5
    PERFORM A-SOLUTION
    MOVE ICOL-4 TO COLUMN-3
    MOVE ICOL-3 TO COLUMN-4
    MOVE ICOL-5 TO COLUMN-5
    PERFORM A-SOLUTION
    MOVE ICOL-5 TO COLUMN-4
    MOVE ICOL-3 TO COLUMN-5
    PERFORM A-SOLUTION
    MOVE ICOL-5 TO COLUMN-3
    MOVE ICOL-3 TO COLUMN-4
    MOVE ICOL-4 TO COLUMN-5
    PERFORM A-SOLUTION
    MOVE ICOL-4 TO COLUMN-4
    MOVE ICOL-3 TO COLUMN-5
    PERFORM A-SOLUTION
    .
A-SOLUTION.
    MOVE CHAR-SET ( 1 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 1 : 1 )
    MOVE CHAR-SET ( COLUMN-2 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 2 : 1 )
    MOVE CHAR-SET ( COLUMN-3 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 3 : 1 )
    MOVE CHAR-SET ( COLUMN-4 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 4 : 1 )
    MOVE CHAR-SET ( COLUMN-5 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 5 : 1 )
    PERFORM SOLUTION-READY
    PERFORM SOLUTIONS-FOR-REMAINING-VALUES
    .
SOLUTIONS-FOR-REMAINING-VALUES.
    MOVE SOLUTION TO SAVE-SOLUTION
    MOVE SOLUTION ( 2 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 1 : 1 )
    MOVE SAVE-IT TO SOLUTION ( 2 : 1 ) 
    PERFORM SOLUTION-READY
    MOVE SAVE-SOLUTION TO SOLUTION
    MOVE SOLUTION ( 3 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 1 : 1 )
    MOVE SAVE-IT TO SOLUTION ( 3 : 1 ) 
    PERFORM SOLUTION-READY
    MOVE SAVE-SOLUTION TO SOLUTION
    MOVE SOLUTION ( 4 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 1 : 1 )
    MOVE SAVE-IT TO SOLUTION ( 4 : 1 ) 
    PERFORM SOLUTION-READY
    MOVE SAVE-SOLUTION TO SOLUTION
    MOVE SOLUTION ( 5 : 1 ) TO SOLUTION ( 1 : 1 )
    MOVE SAVE-IT TO SOLUTION ( 5 : 1 ) 
    PERFORM SOLUTION-READY
    .
SOLUTION-READY.
    ADD 1 TO SOLUTION-COUNT 
    DISPLAY SOLUTION 
    .
```

OK. Specific program for the question. Sort of. The expected answer is probably the Ingo/Valdis Grinbergs one, to learn how to "nest" loops.

What is the program doing? Well, it is getting 1/5 of the permutations, and then relying on the symmetry in those results to generate the remaining 4/5 of the permutations with no further processing beyond rearrangement.

Why are there no loops? Because, since it is known beforehand, the answer is known beforehand. Instead of the loops, which invariably produce the same result, the result has been "hard-coded".

Can the programs be genneralised? Yes. What is the algorithm?

Well, you could describe the code, and work out how to extend it. Or you could look at the data.

The generation of six pairs of two does what? Well, the pairs of two are simply permutations of two values. The six, permutations of three values. Doing the six four times is permutations of four values.

So, to perm five values, apply each of the five individual values to the permutation pattern of four values. To perm four values, apply each of the four individual values to the permutation pattern of three values. To perm three values, apply each of the three individual values to the permutation pattern of two values. To perm two values, apply each of the two individual values to the permutation pattern of one value(!).

So, to perm N values, apply each of the N individual values to the permutation pattern of (N-1) values.

In a general solution, N = 1 requires zero iterations. N = 2 requires one iteration. N = 3 requires two iterations. N = 4 requires six iterations. N = 5 requires 24 iterations. N = N requires (N - 1)! iterations, with N = 1 a special case.

To generate all all data, rather than to hard-code initial solutions, requires the sum. N = 5, from a starting point of no available smaller permutations, requires 24 + 6 + 2 + 1 = 33 iterations.

And yes, this readily lends itself to recursion for a solution. It also lends itself to a solution with no loops at all. This is not COBOL specific, but the same for any language.

Of course, you'd never need more than one invocation per program per different N values. So again, no problem with using recursion.

The problem with recursion in COBOL, is the general unfamiliarity amongst COBOL programmers as to how to do it.

The obvious use for a "slick" version is if having to deal with N's of a "large" size (factorials are involved, so "large" arrives fairly quickly).

The other thing is "clarity". Can the next person along understand what the code is doing.

I'll do a "nice" version if I can find the time..,